# How to compute the stabilizer subgroup of a partition with GAP?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, gap

A partition $P$ of a set $S$ is a set of disjoint subsets of $S$ whose union is $S$. Let $G$ be a subgroup of the symmetric group $S_n$. Define the stabilizer subgroup of $G$ for a partition $P$ of $\{1,2, \dots , n\}$ by $ G_P:= \{g \in G \ | \ gP=P   \} $ where $gP:= \{ \{ga \ | \ a \in p  \} \ | \ p \in P \}$.

*Question*: How to compute explicitly $G_P$ with GAP?

Comment: Such a stabilizer should just be the direct product of smaller symmetric groups right? If we write a stabilizer element in cycle notation, each cycle should contain only elements of a set in the partition.

Comment: @RyleeLyman No, since a partition is defined as set of sets, the sets could be permuted, so it is (if all sets have the same size) the intersection with a wreath product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generically it would be a stabilizer

```
Stabilizer(G,P,OnSetsDisjointSets);
```

(assuming that $P$ is a set of sets in the GAP sense). IIRC this has been introduced only in recent releases, but the underlying function `PartitionStabilizerPermGroup(G,P)` has been around for longer. The calculation involves a backtrack search, and probably offers many possibilities for improvement.

Comment: I just used your answer in the following answer: https://mathoverflow.net/a/338339/34538
at the end of which there is a computation my computer was not able to do. If yours can do it, I would be very interested.